# css content element not showed in if display=flex

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-content

I have a line describing the full company address.
It is made with different pieces

```
<div><b>COMPANY</b>&nbsp;•&nbsp;Address,&nbsp;City&nbsp;•&nbsp;VAT 12345678901</div>
```

In a large screen the div is displayed as one long line:

```
COMPANY • Address line, City • VAT 12345678901
```

But on a small mobile device it is displayed on three lines:

```
     COMPANY • 
Address line, City • 
  VAT 12345678901
```

My goal is to remove the bullets on the small devices.
To accomplish the goal, I defined a `span` element as follow:

```
.bg99 .footer-divider {
    content: "&nbsp;•&nbsp;";
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){ 

    .bg99 div.company div {
        flex-direction: column;    
    }
    .bg99 .footer-divider {
        content: "&nbsp;&nbsp;"
    }
    
  }
```

and changed the line as follow:

```
<div><b>COMPANY</b><span className="footer-divider"/>Address,&nbsp;City<span className="footer-divider"/>VAT 12345678901</div>
```

But the result is that the bullets disappeared on both devices.

Inspecting the browser, I see the CSS class `footer-divider` and the content

```
.bg99 .footer-divider {
    content: "&nbsp;•&nbsp;";
}
```

But the bullets are not visible on the screen. It looks like the rule should not applied.

Any idea?

Comment: Afaik `content` only works for pseudo-elements like ::before. Also, content is inserted as-is, meaning you'd end up with &nbsp; being visible. What you can do is put the bullet point in the span, then hide it on smaller screens: https://jsfiddle.net/fu6L5a1j/

Comment: @ChrisG I thought content could be used to replace content in an element. Have I got this wrong? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

Answer (score 0):

I think first you need to replace "className" with "class" in your html markup

Try below code that might help

HTML

```
<div class="bg99">
<b>COMPANY</b>
<span class="footer-divider">Address,&nbsp;City</span>
<span class="footer-divider">VAT 12345678901</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){

    .bg99 div.company div {
        flex-direction: column;    
    }
    
    .bg99 .footer-divider::before{
        content: "*"
    }
    
  }
```

Comment: I used `className` because the code was in `React-JS`

Comment: got it. Is the above solution working for you ? check this link https://jsfiddle.net/SyamKumarD/xa49vspy/23/

Comment: Don't know! The first comment at the question gave me the solution.

Comment: ok great, happy coding :)